# Show in the tables, only the last statues

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a simple entry in the oracle, there are 3 columns, date, API name and status. I want that in the answer I had not all history, and only the last on each of Names of API (only 7). I will be grateful for your help. I know that asked of the very difficult but I'm just new to oracle.

```html
select l.log_date,l.job_name,l.status from user_scheduler_job_log l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you want the related  status for name and last log_date

```
select  u.job_name, u.status, t.max_date
from user_scheduler_job_log u
INNER JOIN(
  select MAX(l.log_date) max_date, l.job_name
  from user_scheduler_job_log l
  GROUP BY l.job_name
) t on t.max_date = u.log_date 
    AND t.job_name = u.job_name
```